# How would I round minutes to the nearest 5 minute mark in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Currently working on a site where I use moment.js. I want to use jquery only.

I get the current minute using:

```
var minute = moment().minute();
```

but I want to set an alarm starting at the nearest next 5 minute mark.

So say it's 8:38pm now, var minute would be 38. I'd want to set the input to a value of 40 (that is, 40 minutes)

So where my options are:

```
<select id="minuteID">
                    <option value="0">00</option>
                    <option value="5">05</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="35">35</option>
                    <option value="40">40</option>
                    <option value="45">45</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value=55>55</option>
                </select>
```

And I can input the item like so:

```
var minute = moment().minute();
$("#minuteID option[value=" + minute + "]").prop("selected", "selected");
```

How do I make it so that instead of finding the exact option minute, it finds it at intervals of 5 (to the nearest 5 marker).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+round+to+nearest

Comment: My mistake here was searching for "momentjs round to nearest 5"... it didn't occur to me to do it with regular js, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
minute = 5 * Math.round( minute / 5 );
```

will do as you want.

Comment: In even less code, both are great but I'll have to accept this one for efficiency. Thank you also

Comment: Doesn't work if `minute` is 58 or 59. You have to do `minute = (5 * Math.round( minute / 5 )) % 60;` instead.

Comment: @MaximeRossini You're right, I missed that the OP has limited the values from `0` to `55`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var minute = roundToFive(moment().minute());
$("#minuteID option[value=" + minute + "]").prop("selected", "selected");

function roundToFive(num) {
    var temp = num%5;
    if (temp<3)
         return num-temp;
    else
         return num+5-temp;
}
```